# Filter Breaker for iran ip

Tags: wine

I am looking for a software that can visit banned website in Iran(I mean FLTR BRKR). I don't want "TOR" since it is only a browser. I need something to use its proxy. Absolutely something like "PSIPHONE 3" in windows . Neither  don't want to use wine!. i want to use a pure Linux SW. Any help would be appreciated to visit banned websites!

Comment: I think you're looking for a VPN

Comment: Maybe this will help  https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3317/how-can-i-pass-all-wifi-traffic-through-tor

Comment: VPN Ports has been closed in iran. for windows psiphon works. but its ubuntu version even doesnt find server

Comment: There are some paid proxies which worked for me, like iproyal.com (residential proxy service), but I think any other paid proxies would work. It can be configured in Ubuntu setting > network > proxy so all the traffics at OS level is routed through proxy, or at the browser level

Comment: Paid proxies are not secure